# Undefined method `arel_attributes_values' for class `ActiveRecord::Base'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to run

```
$ rails console
```

I get the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method': undefined method `arel_attributes_values' for class `ActiveRecord::Base' (NameError)
```

.............
Other errors follow... that are just tracebacks

My versions are as follows

```
$ gem -v
2.0.5
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41647) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
$ rvm -v 
rvm 1.21.11 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ uname -a
Linux cdv-web01 2.6.18-274.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jul 8 17:36:59 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Do I have to install a gem that I don't know about?

UPDATE: Included is the whole traceback...

```
Warning: NLS_LANG is not set. fallback to US7ASCII.
/home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method': undefined method `arel_attributes_values' for class `ActiveRecord::Base' (NameError)
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method_chain'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_base_ext.rb:116:in `<class:Base>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_base_ext.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_base_ext.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:211:in `block in load_dependency'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:211:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:211:in `block in load_dependency'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:211:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.2/lib/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter.rb:12:in `block in <class:OracleEnhancedRailtie>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:322:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/maintenance_scheduler/app/models/cmts_device.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `block in load_file'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `load_file'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:323:in `require_or_load'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/maintenance_scheduler/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
        from /home/aayerd200/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:63:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

With ReadyForRails4...

Input as...

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
gem 'ruby-oci8'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'prototype-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

[image]

Comment: Include whole traceback, if it mentions any of your project files include them as well.

Comment: It might also be helpful to paste your `Gemfile` contents into [Ready for Rails 4?](http://ready4rails4.net/gemfile_check/new), to make sure that all the gems you're using are compatible...

Comment: does this happen on a bare app? or one you've customized.   have you setup a database.yml yet (curious if it s DB related)

Comment: I do have a database.yml.  I am just moving this application to another server.  It was able to run 'rails console' on the other server.

Comment: So then what is the solution if I have Rails 4? @Doodad  Or should I just revert back to 3.2.8

Comment: it is the oracle adaptor.   see   https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/312

Comment: If you really need that gem, I'm afraid your best bet is to revert back to 3.2.8. You can go up to 3.2.13 if you want though. Edit: From that bug report Doon posted, it seems they are working on it and you can try that specific branch someone posted, but it seems there some bugs still. Ok, let me put all that organized in the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the gem `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` is not compatible with Rails 4.

This is the file which should have that method `arel_attributes_value`:

> http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/…

And here is the file at 3.2-stable branch.

> http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/…

The method is there at the second file (3.2-stable), but it's not in the first (master). So it was probably removed in Rails 4.

If I were you I'd just revert back to 3.2 for now, but if you want to use Rails 4 anyway, it seems there's a branch for Rails 4.

So you go to your Gemfile and change the line

> gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'

to

> gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', github: 'rsim/oracle-enhanced', branch: 'rails4'

and `bundle update`. And that should do it.

Comment: Thanks that did it.  I just reverted to 3.2.8 and it works well.  Now just the problem with testing the connection...  best to you!

Comment: No prob, mate. Best to you too!

Comment: the github repo is not quite correct, should be http://github.com/rsim/oracle... otherwise it prompts for a username

Comment: Oh, I put a random fork there? My god, thank you very much for correcting that. Will edit right now.

Answer (score 0):

The updated version of the **activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter** gem supports Rails 4.

Add this to your gem file

```
gem "activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter", "~> 1.5.0"
```

This worked for me for Rails 4.0.2

Hope this helps.

PS: Here is the [github link](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced) for the gem.